# uninitialized variables and #Bugs:dic.set cannot be executed (is greyed out) issue in WinBUGS

Tags: variables, initialization, winbugs, r2winbugs

I am running the following model using r2WinBUGS package from R.

```
model{
  for (i in 1:Nshim) {
    y.SHIM[i]~ dnorm(mu[i], tau)
    mu[i] <- zeta[PID[i]]+beta0[T[PID[i]]]+beta1[T[PID[i]]]*TIME[i]+beta2[T[PID[i]]]*pow(TIME[i],2)
  }
  for ( k in 1:Mshim){
    zeta[k]~dnorm(0, prec.zeta)
  }

  for ( j in 1:Mshim){
    T[j]~ dcat(p[])
  }
  for ( k in 1:2){
    beta0[k]~dnorm(0.0,1.0E-6)
    beta1[k]~dnorm(0.0, 1.0E-6)
    beta2[k]~dnorm(0.0, 1.0E-6)
  }
  prec.zeta~dgamma(0.1,0.01)
  p[1:2]~ ddirch(alpha[])
  alpha[1] <- 1
  alpha[2] <- 1
  tau~dgamma(0.1,0.1)
  sig2<-1/tau
  sig2.zeta<-1/prec.zeta
}
```

Considering the following initials for 3-chains.

```
init_2quad.SHIM_RI=function(){list(beta0=c(10,15),beta1=rnorm(2),beta2=rnorm(2),zeta=rgamma(70,1,1),T=rbinom(70,1,0.5)+1)
                              list(beta0=c(12,18),beta1=rnorm(2),beta2=rnorm(2),zeta=rgamma(70,1,1),T=rbinom(70,1,0.5)+1)
                              list(beta0=c(15,20),beta1=rnorm(2),beta2=rnorm(2),zeta=rgamma(70,1,1),T=rbinom(70,1,0.5)+1)
                              }
setwd("C:/Users/mnudd/Desktop/IndStudy/WinBUGS14")
mix_2quad.RI_res=bugs(data = SHIM_2quad,model.file = "mix_2Q_SHIM_RI.bug",   
                      inits = init_2quad.SHIM_RI, parameters.to.save = c("beta0","beta1", "beta2", "zeta","T","sig2"),
                      n.chains = 3, n.iter = n.iter_2q.RI, n.burnin = n.burnin_2q.RI, n.thin = n.thin_2q.RI, 
                      bugs.directory = "C:/Users/mnudd/Desktop/IndStudy/WinBUGS14",
                      debug=T,codaPkg=F)
```

Unfortunately each time I run, getting the following warning

```
this chain contains uninitialized variables
inits(3,C:/Users/mnudd/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWQM8aq/inits3.txt)
this chain contains uninitialized variables
gen.inits()
initial values generated, model initialized
thin.updater(10)
update(100)
set(beta0)
set(beta1)
set(beta2)
set(zeta)
set(T)
set(sig2)
set(deviance)
dic.set()
command #Bugs:dic.set cannot be executed (is greyed out)
update(1000)
coda(*,C:/Users/mnudd/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWQM8aq/coda)
```

**How can identify which one is uninitialized and why the bugs can not be executed(grayed out)?
Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.**